# addObserver works locally but not in addon

Tags: ember.js

I have a working Mixin class that I have converted to a **addon** and for reasons that baffle me the identical call to:

```
Ember.addObserver(self, prop, self, Ember.run.bind(self, self.addDynamicObserver, prop));
```

goes no where in the addon but works as expected in the local definition of the Mixin class.

This call can be found in an initializer for the Mixin class:

```
_initialise: function() {
    var self = this;
    try {
        this.eachAttribute(function(prop,meta) {
            if(meta.type === "dictionary") {
                Ember.addObserver(self, prop, self, Ember.run.bind(self, self.addDynamicObserver, prop));
            }
        });         
    } catch (e) {
        console.warning('Dictionary mixin did not initialise. Note: the dictionary mixin should only be used by a Model-derived class.');
    }
}.on('init'),
```

In both cases (*local implementation* versus *addon*):

1. the tests are run on a Model with a 'dictionary' attribute
2. the 'init' event triggers the call to the _initialise()
3. the conditional block where the call to `addObserver()` *is* executed
4. no errors are registered in either implementation approach

However, as stated above, the addon's call to addObserver() never results in the call to `self.addDynamicObserver`.

- The source for the addon can be found here: [source link](https://github.com/lifegadget/ember-dictionary/tree/0.0.1)
- The specific call to addObserver is here: [source link](https://github.com/lifegadget/ember-dictionary/blob/0.0.1/app/mixins/dictionary.js#L81)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ahhh, I think MAYBE this related to my test scripts not waiting for the 'init' event. How does one ensure the init event has fired before running tests? Is there a promise I can grab ahold of in qunit?

Comment: I'm 99% sure this has to do with the `init()` not having fired but I haven't had any luck in deferring unit testing until this event is fired.